# Adding a attribute to all the images in a web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [zoom](https://github.com/fat/zoom.js) which is a simple jQuery plugin for image zooming, as seen on Medium.

It requires adding a `data-action="zoom"` to all the `<img>` tags to work.

Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vpc3pk5/3/).

I want it to work with all the images in a web page by a using a js code that applies the attribute to all `<img>` tags.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/8vpc3pk5/4/

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use attribute setter [`.attr(attributeName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2).

```
$('img').attr("data-action","zoom")
```

see in [action](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/8vpc3pk5/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Add like:

```
$( "img" ).each(function( index ) {
   $(this).attr("data-action","zoom")
});
```